# R How to join by condition with data.table?

Tags: r, join, data.table

After some research, especially here, I discovered what I think is a very interesting method to join two `data.table` by condition :
`DT[WHERE, v := FROM[.SD, on=, x.v]]`  .

Unfortunately, I can not perform this in spite of many attempts.

From DT1 and DT2, I need to create DTres : perform a join only on some DT1 rows.

And DT3 is one of my unsuccessful attempt...

Is it possible to do this ? How to ?

Many thanks for helping.

```
library(data.table)

DT1 <- data.table(crit = rep(c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'),each = 3),
                  num = rep(1:3, 4), 
                  val = rnorm(12)^2)
DT1

DT2 <- data.table(BB = c(1,3),
                  cross = c(128, 183))
DT2

DTres <- data.table(crit = rep(c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'),each = 3),
                    num = rep(1:3, 4), 
                    val = rnorm(12)^2,
                    cross = c(rep(NA,3), 128, NA, 183, rep(NA, 6))
)
DTres

DT3 <- DT1[crit == 'BB', cross := DT2[DT1, on = .('BB' = num), x.cross]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a column of 'crit' in the second dataset, do the join and assign the value of 'cross' from 'DT2' to 'DT1'

```
DT1[DT2[,  c(.(crit = 'BB'), .SD)] , cross := cross, on = .(crit, num = BB)]

DT1
```

---

Or `melt` the second data into 'long 'format

```
DT1[ melt(DT2, id.var = 'cross', variable.name = 'crit'), 
      cross := cross, on = .(crit, num = value)]



DT1
#    crit num          val cross
# 1:   AA   1 4.720241e+00    NA
# 2:   AA   2 2.261093e-01    NA
# 3:   AA   3 5.040239e-01    NA
# 4:   BB   1 3.729867e-01   128
# 5:   BB   2 8.725384e-01    NA
# 6:   BB   3 1.571597e+00   183
# 7:   CC   1 8.494091e-02    NA
# 8:   CC   2 1.965077e-01    NA
# 9:   CC   3 1.221802e-06    NA
#10:   DD   1 5.526632e-03    NA
#11:   DD   2 3.475349e-01    NA
#12:   DD   3 3.233841e-01    NA
```

---

Or another option based on the OP's attempt is

```
DT1[crit == 'BB' & num %in% DT2$BB, 
      cross := .SD[DT2, on = .(num = BB)]$cross]
```

Comment: Thanks, your first option works great for me ! In additionnal, may I join a DT3 to "updating" my cross variable ? `DT3 <- data.table(DD = c(2,3), cross = c(99, 787))` ?

Comment: EDIT : From one of your older post on stack, I tested `DT1[DT3[,  c(.(crit = 'DD'), .SD)] , cross := ifelse(is.na(cross), i.cross, cross), on = .(crit, num = DD)]`. It seems to run well. Do you confirm this ? Thanks !!

Comment: You can use `fifelse` in `data.table`

Comment: Yes of course, this was just an oversight. Thanks for supervising.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `data.table` option

```
DT2[, c(stack(.SD[, .(BB)]), .(cross = cross))][DT1, on = .(ind = crit, values = num)]
```

which gives

```
    values ind cross          val
 1:      1  AA    NA 0.0080997625
 2:      2  AA    NA 0.0001964834
 3:      3  AA    NA 1.2621554895
 4:      1  BB   128 1.8066857886
 5:      2  BB    NA 2.3200035029
 6:      3  BB   183 0.1780571706
 7:      1  CC    NA 1.8521153969
 8:      2  CC    NA 3.0757963595
 9:      3  CC    NA 2.4597679400
10:      1  DD    NA 1.6815750082
11:      2  DD    NA 0.0564519787
12:      3  DD    NA 1.4985435547
```